# Url encoding on pageload not working

Tags: c#, encoding, url-encoding

I wanted to encode my url on page load. It has to work in a way that the page will always be encoded on page load. But it is not working, this page is a standalone page so there are no link to redirect user but I need to get it working for my project.

Please help thanks!

This is my Page_Load code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destinationURL = "http://localhost:2094/PaymentSuccesful";
    string encodeURL = Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
    Response.Redirect(encodeURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Response.Redirect(encodeURL,  false)
```

second parameter Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string encodeURL = Server.UrlPathEncode(destinationURL);
 Response.Redirect(encodeURL,  false)
```